# How to add MFA via Microsoft Authenticator App as second factor after the email, password authentication at sign in flow

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

At the moment we are using Azure B2C with embedded SignIn and Password reset user flows and MFA enabled. Default MFA options is SMS and calls. As this approach worth money and outdated we come up with idea to move MFA to Microsoft Authenticator App. It might be Authentificator App code or Authenticator App notification.

I`ve also tried out the custom TOTP sample and have it working with a QR code for new user sign ups using this sample and policies: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/custom-mfa-totp
It is consists of SignUp user journey for the users which is not our case.

**But, how to include MFA via Microsoft Authenticator App for already registered users to SignIn user journey?**

I guess it is pretty common case but custom policy learning curve is actually vertical line and requires a proper guidance.

Answer (score 1):

The policy linked already handles your requirement. Whereby if a user signs in but has yet to enrol into Authenticator, it forces an enrolment.

Then on every sign in, the user must perform MFA via authenticator.

Comment: Hmm.. But what TrustFrameWorkbase.xml policy can this example (https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/custom-mfa-totp) refer too?

Comment: At this line, the user journey prompts to register for Authenticator App, even for any user who has not already, eg cancelled at Sign Up stage and then tried to Sign In.. https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/custom-mfa-totp/policy/TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml#L332

Comment: Thanks ,finally i was able to make it working. The question is, how to make Authenticator app push notifications instead of code?

Comment: You can’t do push with MS authenticator app. For any other authenticator app, here is a sample for push https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/custom-mfa-authy-app

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any particular reason why MSFT App does not support it? Just curious.